# Google Maps Api v 3 + get all info about marked point

Tags: google-maps

I have a question I would like to mark a point on a map (I know how to do it and it works). Then I want to write in InfoWindow everything about this point. How can I do it?

My add marker function:

```
function placeMarker(location) {

    if (marker != null) {
        removeMarker(marker);
    }
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        title: "aaaa",
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Hello world'
    });
    map.setCenter(location);
    setLatLng(location.lat, location.lng, place);
}
```

I use it:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

**Is anywhere the specyfication where I can find what is it the EVENT object and what kind of properties it has?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`latLng` is the only property the event (currently) has. See [reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MouseEvent).

Comment: Yes I know that is why I asked about this event object. How I can get to know what it is and what properties it has?

Comment: Well, you asked about the `MouseEvent` and its properties. Like I said, it only has this one single property (did you check the link I posted?). If you are asking about the _different types of events_ that are fired, check out the "Event" subsection of the [reference's "Map" section](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map). Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. I was afraid that it has only this latLng property :/ But do you know any way to get info about place by latLng? Maybe geocoder? I will check it ;)

Comment: You mean translating latLng into an address? That's done with [reverse geocoding through the geocoding api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding).